# Name this distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, bivariate-distributions

The [bi-variate Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#Multivariate_Cauchy_distribution) is given by $$ \mathbb{R}^2\ni(x,y)\mapsto\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+1)^{1.5}}\,. $$

What is the name of the following probability distribution:
$$ \mathbb{R}^2\ni(x,y)\mapsto\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+1)^{2}}\,? $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a multivariate $t$-distribution with $\nu = 2$ degrees of freedom, mean $\mu = 0$ and shape matrix $\Sigma = 2I$:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_t-distribution